# Git and gitignore and dokku

Tags: git, github, push, dokku

I have created a project in flask (python), and within my app is `config.py` file which I have in `.gitignore`.

This `.gitignore` found good that `config.py` isn´t upload to git (github.org), but when I have to push to `dokku` (`git push dokku master`), I must include `config.py` but `config.py` is in `.gitignore` so it isn´t push to `dokku`.

So how can I push files which are in `.gitignore` to `dokku` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not being tracked by `git`, you can't push it using git. You may succeed with external service like `rsync` etc, but not with `git`.

Placing your `config.py` in `gitignore` essentially makes it ignorable to git.

The simplest way to overcome this would be to checkin your `config.py` into git, i.e.,

1. Remove it from your `.gitignore`
2. Add it to your repository using

   ```
   git add config.py && git commit -m "adding config.py"
   git push origin master
   ```

In general, if you need some file during the build process, and it can not be autogenerated, you should check-in that file into git.